# Paypal character encoding breaks url string

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm passing item names in my PayPal URL string but as soon as I encounter any that have character encoding it causes the url string to break on submitting to paypal.

For example I'm passing the following item name:

> Active listening - it's a

My paypal url string then outputs as:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?item_name_1=Active listening &#8211;it&#8217;s
```

As you can see its coverting the - and ' this then causes url string to break. If I manually remove the – and ’ it works like normal.

I've set my language encoding in the paypal backend to be UTF-8 and I'm passing UTF-8 on my paypal string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the PayPal manual carefully - it says you should urlencode every value you send to their servers.

Comment: Thank's Fracsi I will give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this by converting the html character using

```
html_entity_decode('string', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

on the item name before passing it to PayPal.

Comment: Hi. I may be hitting a problem similar to yours (in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167842/integrating-paypal-ipn-in-php-not-working). May I ask you where and how you include this html_entity_decode line that you mention as your solution?

Comment: Hi @Michel, It was quite a while ago but from what I remember I included it just before I sent the string accross to paypal. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I presume that means you did it on the whole final string. Not just one field at a time.

Comment: Yes @Michel the whole string from what I remember. It was a long time ago however so I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to to convert them to UTF8 first and then urlencode. Try doing this

```
<?php
echo rawurlencode(utf8_encode($yourvar));
```

Comment: That doe's work but now at paypals checkout end they display as the character encoded values eg. '&#8211;' Rather than -